# Large number and three-digit arithmetic

Tags: numerical-methods, computer-science

I want to use three-digit arithmetic to calculate $16.71 - 15920 \times 0.667$ Is it correct to do it in the following way?

\begin{align*} 
16.71 - 15920 \times 0.667 &= 1.67 \times 10 - 1.06\times 10^4\\
&= 0.00167 \times 10^4 - 1.06\times 10^4 \\
&= -1.05 \times 10^4,
\end{align*}

where $15920 \times 0.667 = 10618.64$.

Comment: The correctness of this calculation depends on the rounding mode and the exact computation model for the operations. If you use only 3 digits also in the internal steps, then $1.67×10$ becomes zero when aligning the operands for the subtraction. If the internal steps of the operations can use more digits, then the last digit of the result depends on the rounding mode, you used something like "rounding to zero".

Comment: @LutzL My professor said that we preserve the first three non-zero numbers, so I think $0.00167 \times 10^4$ is okay. What do you mean by rounding mode? Could you give an example?

Comment: I meant the exact internal steps to carry out the single operations. If you line up the operands as $\pmatrix{0.00|167\\1.06|000}×10^4$ then initial rounding renders the first operand to zero. If you have a guard digit, then the subtraction of $\pmatrix{0.001|67\\1.060|00}×10^4\to -1.058×10^4$ gives your result by just chopping off the additional digit, or $-1.06×10^4$ using the more usual rounding.

Answer (score 0):

I would write $$\frac{1671}{100}-15920\times \frac{667}{1000}=\frac{16710-15920\times 667}{1000}=-\frac{10601930}{1000}$$

Comment: I think we are trying to calculate it like how a computer would do.

Comment: @user398843 : A computer would add one or two guard digits for working, internal precision, and only round to 3 digits at the end of the computation. This would give a similar result.